How to solve TypeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object is not subscriptable
I am trying to replicate the SigNet : Writer Independent Offline Signature Verification.
While trying to run module to train the dataset I am coming up with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../trainer_keras.py", line 48, in <module>
    train_datagen = DataGenerator(ds_train,**params)
  File "../IDG.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.labels = df["label"]
TypeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object is not subscriptable

The code (snippet) from where the error is being generated is:
input_a = Input(shape=(155,220,3))
input_b = Input(shape=(155,220,3))

base_net = get_base_net()
processed_a = base_net(input_a)
processed_b = base_net(input_b)

distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance,output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([processed_a, processed_b])
model = Model([input_a, input_b], distance)

optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop()
model.compile(loss=contrastive_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[accuracy])

params={
    'dim': (155,220),
    'batch_size': 32,
    'n_channels': 3,
    'shuffle': False
    }
ds_train = get_dataset('train')
ds_val = get_dataset('val')
train_datagen = DataGenerator(ds_train,**params) # Error being generated here
...
...

The segment of code with function DataGenerator is:
class DataGenerator(seqnc):
    
    def __init__(self, df, batch_size=32, dim=(155,220), n_channels=3, shuffle=True):
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.df = df
        self.labels = df["label"] # Error is pointing to this line
        ...
        ...

Tried to search for issues related to it but nothing I found which could be used to resolve it.
Hope I will get some direction on the forum.
Thanks
